# mysql 3.23 select from one table if value do not exist in table 2 or if exist and date>datenow select it also

Tags: mysql

Make query in MYSQL 3.23 to select from one table if value do not exist in table 2 or if exist and date>now date(in table 2 exist field with date when is added)  select it also.

I make it in mysql 5.22.25 i thik (i deleted it), but i istalled mysql 3.23 and this query do not work.

Is possible that problem is in .dll (conectors)

I use  select * from x where ... and ... not in (select ........)

Mysql say that error in  "in (select ........)" .

Can i use IN in mysql 3.23?

Comment: Update your MySQL server. Really. I can't find even good manual in the official web-site. (Only common for 4.0 & 3.23)

Comment: You could use select * From Table1 Where (select count(id) From Table2) = 0 OR ((select count(id) From Table2) > 0 and date(date_field_name) > NOW());

Comment: i know that ver 3.23 is old, but all is based on it and transfer to ver 5 will be very hard and i need only these change to make. All is good except this problem.

Comment: select * From Table1 Where (select count(id) From Table2) = 0 OR ((select count(id) From Table2) > 0 and date(date_field_name) > NOW());




                NOT WORK selece ...select                                                   


---------------------------
SQL-error(1064)

You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'select id From serfinprogress= 0' at line 1
---------------------------
ОК   
---------------------------

Comment: 3.2.3 !? You should return it immediately to the museum. (When I first got in contact with MySQL in 2003 or 2004, it was nearly outdated AFAIR...)